# Using a variable to define default value in a form input

Tags: forms, variables, default

I have a variable called `totaldue`, which I want to use as the default value when submitting a form.  I have the code

```
input type="number" name="sum-due" readonly="readonly" value=totaldue
```

But this doesn't display the content of totaldue in the form.

Is it possible to do this and if so what is the correct syntax?

Thx- Marie

Comment: Is this a javascript variable, or a server language variable?

Answer (score 5):

> You can't assign variable to textbox via HTML.  Instead place the value directly

```
input type="number" name="sum-due" readonly="readonly" value="5"
```

This is only possible using `javascript` or `jQuery`.

**For eg:**

```
  <input id="my-input" type="number" name="sum-due" readonly="readonly" />
```

**JS:**

```
var totaldue = 5;
document.getElementById('my-input').value = totaldue;
```

**UPDATES:**

From your comments,

```
<script>
    var totaldue = 10;
    document.getElementById('paythis').value = totaldue;
</script>

<form id="pay1" action="hotguidebelize-com.cgi-data.com/webform/5627816.cgi"; method="post">
    <label>Total amount due:</label>
    <input id="paythis" type="number" name="sum-due" readonly="readonly" />
    <input type="submit" value="Proceed To Payment" />
</form>
```

As I said before you can't assign variable to textbox via HTML.  Following are the mistakes:

(1) There is no variable `totaldue` assigned in your javascript.

```
var totaldue = 5;
```

(2) Try using `<label>` tag.  More Information from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

(3) You're using `document.getElementById` which refers `id` selector.  But you haven't specified the id in your `input` tag.  More Information from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

```
<input id="paythis" type="number" name="sum-due" readonly="readonly" />
```

Here is simple [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vkxky/) I have created for you.

Feel free to ask your doubts, when I get time I will reply back or you will get help from others.

Comment: As a total newbie I am lost.  So I know have   <script>
  document.getElementById('paythis').value = totaldue;
</script>

<form id="pay1" action="https://hotguidebelize-com.cgi-data.com/webform/5627816.cgi" method="post">

Total amount due: <input type="number" name="sum-due" readonly="readonly" value=paythis>

<input type="submit" value="Proceed To Payment" />

</form>  but it just displays the word paythis and not the number from the variable.  I know this is probably really basic stuff but I'm not getting it!

Comment: @MarieCarrollRigby Updated my answer.  Take time to learn things.

Comment: One comment about the script part of the code. You can save a line by assigning the return value directly to the field. For example.  <script>document.getElementById('paythis').value = 10;</script>

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set a default value in the html element you have two options

option 1

```
input type="number" name="sum-due" readonly="readonly" value="your_literal_value"
```

option 2 - using javascript/jquery (if you are allowed to use)

html

```
<input type="number" id="totalDueTextbox" name="sum-due" readonly="readonly" value="your_literal_value" />
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

 var totaldue = 200;
 $("#totalDueTextbox").val(totaldue);
});
```